# CakePHP 2: Passing Buttons in an element depending on view

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, block, cakephp-2.2

Id like to pass buttons from the cakePHP 2 (note: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.1) into an Element in `app/View/Elements/Toolbar.ctp`

```
<div class="actions">
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New User'), array('action' => 'add'), array('class' => 'btn btn-small',)); ?>
</div>
```

Above is an example of the button.
Depending on the view, I'd like to pass in different Buttons with different actions.
How do I do that? With `Elements`, `Blocks`, `requestaction()` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cakephp way doing would look like this

In view

```
<?= $this->element('toolbar', array('button' => $button_type)) ?>
```

in element there will be variable called `$button` available. Note that `$button_type` variable is also available in element.

That should do it